# Regex to match trimmed string consisting of words separated by only 1 space char

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am looking for a regex to validate input in C#. The regex has to match an arbitrary number of words which are separated with only 1 space character in between. The matched string cannot start or end with whitespace characters (this is where my problem is).

**Example:** `some sample input 123`

**What I've tried:** `/^(\S+[ ]{0,1})+$/gm` this pattern almost does what is required but it also matches 1 trailing space.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this one and it seems to work:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\S+([ ]{1}\S+)*$");
```

It checks if your string starts with a word followed by zero or more entities of a single white space followed by a word. So trailing white spaces are not allowed.